# Retrive unique records from an access table which does not have a fixed structure

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want only the unique records in same or new table. And I want to do this with different tables (having duplicate records) in access database through same code.

The flow should be like:

**input table ------VBA MODULE------> table with unique records**

I am able to do this group by function but for that i have to use field names in query. But field names will differ from table to table.

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code? How did you try to implement Sergey S.'s solution? Help us help you!

Comment: @ vacip: I have tried creating a query in access design query and sql view. it is giving an error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data", Also, i have tried using DISTINCTROW, i am not getting error with this but it is not giving unique rows. When i copy the same table in excel and select the whole range and click "remove duplicates" i am getting the desired output.

Comment: Please post the sql code that generates the error. (Go to SQL view, and copy-paste the whole code here.)

Comment: I got it....the error is caused by a Memo field in my table....check out this link....[link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896950)....now this field may or may not be present in all the tables...i dont know how should i handle this thing now..

Comment: Cool, glad you figured this one out. Your link also has a Workaround part, try following the steps there.

Comment: yeah i am trying...thank you @vacip for your time..i will let you know if it works..

Answer (score 4):

Just use query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyAnyTable
```

Comment: it is giving an error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data" the table has approx 30K records.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. No need for VBA really, but you can put this in a macro to automate it. Since OP didn't post any code, there really is nothing more to be said here.